# Maven: How to use a build.gradle file?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, pom.xml

I'm a complete beginner with both Maven and Gradle. I have a working Maven project. Now I want to add a bunch of classes from another project which was built using Gradle. I want to take classes from the Gradle project and use it in my Maven project. When I copy the classes into my Maven project, I get a bunch of dependency errors. To resolve those errors I would like to add the required stuff to my `pom.xml` file.

**Basically**, I want to add all dependencies specified in a `build.gradle` file, to my `pom.xml` file.

The `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>10</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>  

  </build>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgrapht-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-jdk1.5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgrapht-jdk1.5</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-ext -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgrapht-ext</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>27.0-jre</version>
      <!-- or, for Android: -->
      <!--  <version>27.0-android</version>  -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.trove4j/trove4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.trove4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>trove4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

</project>
```

The `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.rapidminer.com/content/groups/public/' }
    }   
}


plugins { id 'com.rapidminer.extension' version '0.8.2' }

// Define Maven artifact repositories
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.rapidminer.com/content/groups/public/' }
    ivy {
        url "https://github.com/rapidprom/rapidprom-libraries/raw/${project.properties["version"]}/prom/"
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[module]-[revision]/[module]-[revision].[ext]"
            artifact "[module]-[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"
            ivy "[module]-[revision]/ivy-[module]-[revision].xml"
        }
    }
    ivy {
        url "https://github.com/rapidprom/rapidprom-libraries/raw/${project.properties["version"]}/thirdparty/lib/"
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[module]-[revision]/[module]-[revision].[ext]"
            ivy "[module]-[revision]/ivy-[module]-[revision].xml"
        }
    }
    ivy {
        url "https://github.com/rapidprom/rapidprom-libraries/raw/${project.properties["version"]}/thirdparty/resource/"
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[module]-[revision]/[module]-[revision].[ext]"
            ivy "[module]-[revision]/ivy-[module]-[revision].xml"
        }
    }   
}

extensionConfig {

    // The extension name
    name 'RapidProM'

    /*
     * The artifact group which will be used when publishing the extensions Jar
     * and for package customization when initializing the project repository.
     *
     */
    groupId = 'org.rapidprom'

    /*
     * The extension vendor which will be displayed in the extensions about box
     * and for customizing the license headers when initializing the project repository.
     *
     */
    vendor = "Eindhoven University of Technology"

    /*
     * The vendor homepage which will be displayed in the extensions about box
     * and for customizing the license headers when initializing the project repository.
     *
     */
    homepage = "www.rapidprom.org"

    // enable shadowJar before rapidminer dependency (otherwise build fails)
    shadowJar {
        zip64 true
    }

    // define RapidMiner version and extension dependencies
    dependencies {
        rapidminer '7.2.0'
        //extension namespace: 'text', version: '7.2.0'
    }
}

// Define third party library dependencies
dependencies {

    compile group:"org.rapidprom", name:"ProM-Framework", version:"31245"
    compile "org.rapidprom:AcceptingPetriNet:6.7.93"
    compile "org.rapidprom:AlphaMiner:6.5.47"
    compile "org.rapidprom:Animation:6.5.50"
    compile "org.rapidprom:ApacheUtils:6.7.88"
    compile "org.rapidprom:BasicUtils:6.7.104"
    compile "org.rapidprom:BPMN:6.5.56"
    compile "org.rapidprom:BPMNConversions:6.5.48"
    compile "org.rapidprom:CPNet:6.5.84"
    compile "org.rapidprom:DataAwareReplayer:6.7.563"
    compile "org.rapidprom:DataPetriNets:6.5.291"
    compile "org.rapidprom:DottedChart:6.5.17"
    compile "org.rapidprom:EvolutionaryTreeMiner:6.7.154"
    compile "org.rapidprom:EventStream:6.5.72"
    compile "org.rapidprom:FeaturePrediction:6.5.61"
    compile "org.rapidprom:Fuzzy:6.5.33"
    compile "org.rapidprom:GraphViz:6.7.185"
    compile "org.rapidprom:GuideTreeMiner:6.5.18"
    compile "org.rapidprom:HeuristicsMiner:6.5.49"
    compile "org.rapidprom:HybridILPMiner:6.7.116"
    compile "org.rapidprom:InductiveMiner:6.7.297"
    compile "org.rapidprom:InductiveVisualMiner:6.7.413"
    compile "org.rapidprom:Log:6.7.293"
    compile "org.rapidprom:LogDialog:6.5.42"
    compile "org.rapidprom:LogProjection:6.5.38"
    compile "org.rapidprom:ModelRepair:6.5.12"
    compile "org.rapidprom:Murata:6.5.54"
    compile "org.rapidprom:PetriNets:6.7.95"
    compile "org.rapidprom:PNetAlignmentAnalysis:6.5.35"
    compile "org.rapidprom:PNAnalysis:6.7.122"
    compile "org.rapidprom:PNetReplayer:6.7.99"
    compile "org.rapidprom:PTConversions:6.5.3"
    compile "org.rapidprom:PomPomView:6.5.36"
    compile "org.rapidprom:SocialNetwork:6.5.35"
    compile "org.rapidprom:StreamAlphaMiner:6.5.15"
    compile "org.rapidprom:StreamAnalysis:6.5.38"
    compile "org.rapidprom:StreamInductiveMiner:6.5.42"
    compile "org.rapidprom:TransitionSystems:6.7.71"
    compile "org.rapidprom:TSPetriNet:6.5.35"
    compile "org.rapidprom:Uma:6.5.46"
    compile "org.rapidprom:Woflan:6.7.59"
    compile "org.rapidprom:XESLite:6.7.217"
    compile "org.rapidprom:Weka:6.7.3"
}
```

Comment: Do you require everything to build simultaneously (maven calling gradle) or can you build and install the gradle libraries to maven, then build your maven based project using those libraries?

Comment: @the_storyteller The latter. I don't need the Gradle project, I just want to build and install the Gradle libraries with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy to Maven, use the `maven` plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.company'
version = '1.0.0.6'
// To build and push development snapshots, add a suffix to the name
// version = '1.0.0.6-SNAPSHOT'

artifacts {
    archives jar
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            snapshotRepository(url: 'https://maven.repo/bla') {
                authentication(userName: snapshotUser, password: snapshotPassword)
            }
            repository(url: 'https://maven.repo/bla') {
                authentication(userName: releaseUser, password: releasePassword);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can both install to a remote repository by running the `uploadArchives` task, (example above is `https://maven.repo/bla`), or install to `~/.m2/repository` which is *maven local* using the `install` task.

```
gradle install uploadArchives
```

If you choose to install to maven local, you can add a dependency on maven local to other gradle projects by using `dependencies { mavenLocal() }`, or including it in your `pom.xml`

```
<settings <!-- bla --> >
  <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
</settings>
```

Comment: I'm not able to follow your answer :/ I understand that you suggest modifying the .gradle file, then running a Gradle command which is supposed to generate an equivalent pom.xml file? Could you point me to the steps which I need to take for my specific example?

Comment: Sorry. Add the above gradle code to your gradle file, and run `gradle build install`, which will build the gradle project and install it to `mavenLocal`. After that, add the `localRepository` code to your `pom.xml` `<settings/>` block, and theoretically you'll be able to use the gradle-build artifact from your mavenLocal repository.

If you want to install to a remote repository, you'll need to change the remote repo's url and credentials, and run `gradle uploadArchives`.